# HTTP Posting large string fails with error code 317

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

I am HTTP posting a large string of text to my server. The string of text is the contents of a file that is 800kb in size. My function `HttpSendRequest()` fails with the error code `317` from `GetLastError()`.

```
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, -1, (LPVOID)authData.c_str(), authData.size() * sizeof(TCHAR))
```

What does the error 317 mean? I've googled but could not find what this error means. And can I/should I post such large strings (file contents) this way? Should I use a different winapi method?

**Edit** Useful info:
- The server is Apache
- I am HTTP posting to my PHP script. The data is not posted in the query string just regular posting like a form.
- My website uses WordPress CMS. I know wordpress limits the max upload size for some files. Maybe WP also limits the http post size aswell?

Comment: By "my server" do you mean HTTP server written from scratch or some web application (e.g. ASP.NET) behind some existing web server (like IIS, nginx or Apache)?

Comment: @wirher No its a standard shared server from GoDaddy. So Linux running PHP. I am posting to my PHP script.

Comment: 317 indicates a message string resource error, are you printing GetLastErrror immediately after you get a FALSE return? If you are using FormatMessage or similar to get an error string thats what needs fixing first